# Conceptual doubt in a limit question.

Tags: limits

Consider this question$$
\lim:\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2\left(\sqrt {(1-\cos\frac{1}{n})\sqrt {(1-\cos\frac{1}{n})\sqrt {(1-\cos\frac{1}{n})}}.......\infty}\right)
$$

Now I assumed$$
(\sqrt {(1-\cos\frac{1}{n})\sqrt {(1-\cos\frac{1}{n})\sqrt {(1-\cos\frac{1}{n})}}.......\infty} = X
$$

After Squaring both sides I got$$
X^2 = X(1-\cos\frac{1}{n})
$$

Also since $(1-\cos\frac{1}{n})$ is under the square root, hence it must be greater than or equal to 0.

Hence I won't consider ($-$) sign before $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ in the formula $$
-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}\over2a
$$

Okay so after solving the equation I got only 1 root.  $$
X = 1-\cos\frac{1}{n}
$$
Now let $n$ = $\frac{1}{x}$ so that when $n\to\infty$ then $x\to0$.

Now, our limit got reduced to only this$$ 
\lim:\lim_{x\to0}\frac{X}{x^2} 
$$
OR
$$
\lim:\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(1-\cos x)}{x^2}
$$
And now I got my answer as:  $$
\frac{1}{2}
$$
But my answer didn't match the answer given in the book.

So please could someone tell what's wrong in my approach or if all the assumptions and arguments which I made are correct or not?

I spent a lot of time on this question and also I can't think of any other method to solve this question.

Thankyou!

Comment: What's the answer in the book?

Comment: The answer in the book is 0

Comment: I think your argument is basically OK.

Comment: There are two separate problems (i) evaluate $\lim_{m\to\infty} a^{\frac{1}{2}}a^{\frac{1}{2^2}}\dots a^{\frac{1}{2^m}}$; like you I get $a$ (because all terms exceed $a^{\frac{1}{2}}$ )[although you make too  much of a business of solving $X^2=aX$!] (ii) evaluate $\lim n^2 (1-\cos\frac{1}{n})$, like you I get $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Could you please explain me your method, as I didn't get it.

Comment: The other solution to $X^2 = X\left(1 - \cos\frac{1}{n}\right)$ is $X = 0$, and taking $X = 0$ would produce the solution in the book... but I agree that the value of $X$ is $1 - \cos\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: I think you are correct. I spent plenty of time on this question too, trying different methods as well as graphing the functions. $\frac{1}{2}$ seems to be a perfectly valid solution. $X=0$ would probably be an alternative solution to the quadratic that you solve, leading to the answer in the book as pointed out by @TheoBendit. But either way, I feel your answer is perfectly okay!

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot. I was also confused and I think that the answer given in my book is wrong because not so many people can be wrong at the same time